# Position fixed and margin on right confusion

Tags: html, css

```css
button{
    
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Buy Now</button>
```

Why my button is not centered? It seems like more the right. Why does position fixed doesn't relative to the body's width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HI now **remove** your `width` or `margin` and **define** to `left` `right` `top` `bottom` according to your **design** .

and now change your  **button** to `span` or `div` as like this

```css
span.btn{
    
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    right:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="btn">Buy Now</span>
```

Comment: your result look not different than mine.

Comment: @AliceXu want do you want can u explain me

Comment: @AliceXu now i have updated to my answer now remove to width as like this

Comment: @AliceXu You can't use 100% with 10px margin.

Comment: @AliceXu now i have change to in my answer please look once again

Answer (score 2):

```css
button{
    
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:calc(100% - 20px);
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Buy Now</button>
```

Comment: How bout not using cal() I know I can use cal() to solve my problem but I want to support old phone.

Answer (score 2):

From the other answers and comments I think you want this.

```css
button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Buy Now</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the trickery of the margin that had you confused.
Because your button have  `margin: 10px;`, your button will now have an extra width of 20px (10px left and right). You will have to reduce the 100% width by 20px. Hence, the `width: calc(100% - 20px);`

```css
button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button>Buy Now</button>
```

> or you could remove the margin.

Answer (score 1):

The margin is messing with your page. What you need to do is this:

```css
button{
    
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:90%;
    left: 0; /* <- Set the left property always. */
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto; /* left: 0, right: 0, margin: 0 auto sets the appropriate margins. */
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    /* margin: 10px; <- NO MARGIN! */
}
```

```html
<button>Buy Now</button>
```

Comment: 90%? that's not accurate, what if i want 10px left and right?

Comment: `width: calc(100% - 20px);` will do it. We set it to 100% and remove 20px – 10px for the left, 10px for the right. :)

Also, you'll need to do two widths, because calc() needs to be prefixed for webkit. So, also add `width: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);` above the `width: calc(100% - 20px);` rule. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
button{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left: 50%; /* <- Set the left property always. */
    right: 50%;
    width:100px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
}

<button>Buy Now</button>
```

Comment: I would recommend you to include some explanation on how this helps.

Comment: Now the button will be fixed position at the bottom of you page and it will be placed at the center bottom due to the left and right positions are 50% of the page if you decrease your page size also than it will be taking the decreased screen size

Comment: I would also recommend you to includethe explanation within the answer rather than as a comment by using the edit link.

Answer (score 1):

Add a wrapping `div`.

```css
.btn{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin:10px;
}
button{
width:100%;
background:#000;
color:#fff;
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
<button>Buy Now</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want to know the reason why you div is always overflowing to right even when margin right-is used. So brother, you must know that the **default property of every block level element is to float left and uses the browser left edge as the initial scale.** So the elements tend to overflow right taking margin from left not right.

YOu must use below code:

```
buttom{

position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:calc(100% - (X*2)px);// X is the margin you give. X * 2, its because margin-left + margin-right.
background:#000;
color:#fff;
padding:10px;
margin:Xpx;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button>Buy Now</button>
```